# Exercise 24 - Find the model number of the product (PC, laptop, or printer) with the highest price. Result set: model

Tags: sql, alias

I have this SQL statement and it returns the correct answer but it's too long as I can't figure out how to reuse the alias, so I had wrote the whole SELECT again:

```
select model from
(
select model, max(price) as maxt from
(
select model,price from pc where price in (select max(price) from pc)
union
select model,price from laptop where price in (select max(price) from laptop)
union
select model,price from printer where price in (select max(price) from printer)
) as ab
group by model
) as ba
where maxt in 

(
select max(maxt) from (

select model, max(price) as maxt from
(
select model,price from pc where price in (select max(price) from pc)
union
select model,price from laptop where price in (select max(price) from laptop)
union
select model,price from printer where price in (select max(price) from printer)
) as aba
group by model
) as bac )
```

The exercise is :
Find the model number of the product (PC, laptop, or printer) with the highest price.
Result set: model.

Table Laptop

```
code    model   speed   ram hd      price       screen
------------------------------------------------------
1       1298    350     32  4.0     700.0000    11
2       1321    500     64  8.0     970.0000    12
3       1750    750     128 12.0    1200.0000   14
4       1298    600     64  10.0    1050.0000   15
5       1752    750     128 10.0    1150.0000   14
6       1298    450     64  10.0    950.0000    12
```

The PC table:

```
code     model  speed   ram hd  cd  price
-------------------------------------------------------
1   1232    500 64  5.0 12x 600.0000
10  1260    500 32  10.0    12x 350.0000
11  1233    900 128 40.0    40x 980.0000
12  1233    800 128 20.0    50x 970.0000
2   1121    750 128 14.0    40x 850.0000
3   1233    500 64  5.0 12x 600.0000
4   1121    600 128 14.0    40x 850.0000
5   1121    600 128 8.0 40x 850.0000
6   1233    750 128 20.0    50x 950.0000
7   1232    500 32  10.0    12x 400.0000
8   1232    450 64  8.0 24x 350.0000
9   1232    450 32  10.0    24x 350.0000
```

Printer table:

```
code    model   color   type    price
-----------------------------------------
1   1276    n   Laser   400.0000
2   1433    y   Jet 270.0000
3   1434    y   Jet 290.0000
4   1401    n   Matrix  150.0000
5   1408    n   Matrix  270.0000
6   1288    n   Laser   400.0000
```

Table Product:

```
maker   model   Type
-----------------------
A       1232    PC
A       1233    PC
A       1276    Printer
A       1298    Laptop
A       1401    Printer
A       1408    Printer
A       1752    Laptop
B       1121    PC
B       1750    Laptop
C       1321    Laptop
D       1288    Printer
D       1433    Printer
E       1260    PC
E       1434    Printer
E       2112    PC
E       2113    PC
```

Comment: You might want to re-edit your question and use the `{}` button on blocks of code and other pieces of text where you want a fixed layout (and syntax highlighting too) rather than adding all of those `<br/>`s.

Comment: What is the expected result? The one most expensive item, be it a laptop, a PC or a printer, or three rows with the most expensive article of *each* product type?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this query is equal your query:

```
select model from
(
select model,price from pc where price = (select max(price) from pc)
union
select model,price from laptop where price = (select max(price) from laptop)
union
select model,price from printer where price = (select max(price) from printer)
) as ab
where price = 
(select max(price) from
(
select model,price from pc where price = (select max(price) from pc)
union
select model,price from laptop where price = (select max(price) from laptop)
union
select model,price from printer where price = (select max(price) from printer)
) as abc) ;
```

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you using my friend?

Comment: I'm using the exercises from the following site "sql-ex.ru"

Answer (score 2):

---

```
WITH ALL_PRODUCTS
AS
(SELECT MODEL,PRICE FROM PC
UNION
SELECT MODEL,PRICE FROM LAPTOP
UNION
SELECT MODEL,PRICE FROM PRINTER)
SELECT
MODEL FROM ALL_PRODUCTS
WHERE PRICE = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM ALL_PRODUCTS)
```

---

Right.

The result of Your query:

MODEL
1750

---

With option works for MS SQL server, I think even in oracle

Comment: it strange i have exactly the same query and it could'n go thought

Comment: I found the problem I was using `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2):

there are a lot of ways to solve the task, here is the most costless one as for me:

```
select model from
(
select model,price from pc
union all
select model,price from laptop
union all
select model,price from printer
) as A
where price = (select max(price) from
(
select model,price from pc
union all
select model,price from laptop
union all
select model,price from printer
) as B)
```

and one more using WITH:

```
with max
as 
(select model, price from pc
union 
select model, price from laptop
union 
select model, price from printer)

select model from max
where price = (select max(price) from max)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as (
    Select model,price from pc 
    union select model, price from laptop 
    union select model, price from printer)
select model
from cte 
where price=(select max(price) from cte)
```

How about a shorter version?

Comment: Quite apt solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate things. There's no need for "alias reusing". An alias is a way to give a table or column another name. Either to have less to write or to distinguish tables when you join 2 times the same or something. You don't have to do that. Here's the "teach a man to fish" method:

**[(Source) The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)**

*Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.*

This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.

**Uncorrelated subquery:**

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

**LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows values will be NULL.

Comment: can't figure out the answer from your example. I have three tables from which I have to extract the model with maximum price.

Comment: In fact I have 4 tables. I need the maker of that model with the maximum price from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given by a friend:

```
select distinct G1.model from

(select G.model,G.price,rank() over (order by G.price desc) as r from 

(
select a.model,a.price from

(Select model, price,rank() over (order by price desc) as r from pc) a

where a.r = 1

union
select a.model,a.price from 

(Select model, price,rank() over (order by price desc) as r from laptop) a where a.r = 1
union
select a.model,a.price from

(Select model, price ,rank() over (order by price desc) as r from printer) a where a.r = 1
) G

) G1 where G1.r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with model_price_out as(
select model, price from PC group by model,price having price= max(price)
union
select model, price from Laptop group by model,price having price = max(price)
union 
select model, price from printer group by model,price having price =max(price)
)
select model
from model_price_out
where price >= all( select price from model_price_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 with pro as 
(select model,price from PC where price=(select MAX(price) from PC) 
UNION ALL 
select model,price from Laptop where price=(select MAX(price) from Laptop)
UNION ALL 
select model,price from Printer where price=(select MAX(price) from Printer) ) 
select model from pro where price>= (select MAX(price) from pro) group by model
```

Answer (score 0):

My anwser is

```
SELECT  model FROM (SELECT model, price from pc
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc)
UNION
SELECT model, price from laptop
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop)
UNION
SELECT model, price from printer
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer) ) AS l1
WHERE price = (SELECT TOP(1) MAX(price) FROM (SELECT model, price from pc
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc)
UNION
SELECT model, price from laptop
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop)
UNION
SELECT model, price from printer
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer))AS l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer

```
Select distinct model from(
select model, price from pc 
union all
select model, price from printer
union all
select model, price from laptop
) x
where price >= all(
select max(price) from pc 
union all
select max(price) from printer
union all
select max(price) from laptop
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using Rank function.Bbelow is the query:

```
select model from
(
select model,price,rank() over (order by price desc) as rnk_1 from
(
select model,price from
(
select model,price,rank() over(order by price desc) as Rnk from laptop 
)a where a.rnk=1
union
select model,price from
(
select model,price,rank() over(order by price desc) as Rnk from pc
)a where a.rnk=1
union
select model,price from
(
select model,price,rank() over(order by price desc) as Rnk from printer 
)a where a.rnk=1
)b 
)c where c.rnk_1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same question:
Find the printer models having the highest price. Result set: model, price.

the following code seemed to work as well

```sql
select model, price
from
printer
where 
price = (select max(price) from printer)
order by price desc
```